# NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.MongoNamespace.checkDatabaseNameValidity error in jmeter while trying to do performance test on mongoDB collection

Tags: java, mongodb, jmeter, load-testing

I am trying to connect to mongo collection to perform some load tests on it. but getting some error.

Can anyone please help me with the same?

DatabaseName and CollectionName I have stored in user defined variables.

Code I am using:

```
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import org.bson.Document;
import java.util.Arrays;

// Connect to the client
try {
    
    MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://<userName>:<password>@prodoperationalcluster1-shard-00-00-pri.z1wts.mongodb.net:27017,prodoperationalcluster1-shard-00-01-pri.z1wts.mongodb.net:27017,prodoperationalcluster1-shard-00-02-pri.z1wts.mongodb.net:27017/myFirstDatabase?ssl=true&replicaSet=atlas-44ekvq-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority");
    
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase(vars.get("databaseName"));
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection(vars.get("collectionName"));  

    vars.putObject("collection", collection);
    
    return "Connected to " + vars.get("collectionName");    
}
catch (Exception e) {
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
    SampleResult.setResponseCode("500");
    SampleResult.setResponseMessage("Exception: " + e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to help you with the same we need to know what the same [MongoDB java drivers](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/) you have in JMeter Classpath because if for example you downloaded the same driver .jar and [BSON jar](https://www.mongodb.com/json-and-bson) is not the same you will get the same error.

You can see [Jar Hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell) for the same

Also ensure that the versions of MongoDB Java Client drivers and the [version of MongoDB on the server side](https://database.guide/7-ways-to-check-your-mongodb-version/) are the same because you cannot use the versions which are not the same for the same.

Check out [MongoDB Performance Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mongodb-performance) article for more information on the same.